# Column ID skipped whenever it encounter a data duplicate

Tags: database, postgresql, database-sequence

I have a table named `email_recipients` and an `ID` is skipped whenever there is a duplicate in `email`.

```
CREATE TABLE email_recipients(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
email_address varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
last_name varchar(255),
first_name varchar(255),
active boolean
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is normal.

The `DEFAULT` value has to be evaluated *before* the insertion, and if the `INSERT` fails for any reason, the sequence value still has been consumed.

This is because sequences are non-transactional for performance reasons, which is a feature.

Don't strive for a “gap-less” sequence, it offers no benefit, only pain.